# ArrayAdapter works during Debug, not any other time

Tags: java, debugging, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a program that is populating a Listview using a custom Array Adapter. If I just run the app on a phone or emulator, is ends up showing up blank. If I step through the code using the debugger, once I reach the very end, it shows the data exactly like it should. What is happening?

The custom Array adapter EventAdapter.java is here: 
http://pastebin.com/kZNN2Fdh

EventsActivity.java is here:
http://pastebin.com/JQFeY1k2﻿

For the record, the Log.v's inside each of the IF statements in EventAdapter.java do not run unless I step through the code using the debugger with breakpoints.

Comment: Does it behave the same after a clean build?

Comment: Yes, same exact behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I had to call `mEventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` at the end of `handleSiteResponse();`